# Autocomplete dictionary from a RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, richtextbox

While this code works fine in my RichTextBox, how do you do it from a dictionary in VB?

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'AutoComplete.Add("do")

        AutoComplete.Add("double")
        AutoComplete.Add("Apple")
        AutoComplete.Add("Car")
        AutoComplete.Add("Table")
        AutoComplete.Add("Plate")
```

How do you do this from a dictionary in VB?

Comment: Want you add all words from richtextbox to autocomplete...?

Comment: I want to add my dictionary file from the desktop without putting all the words in the Autocomplete.Add() method.

Comment: Anybody willing to help?

Answer (score 4):

So this isn't an actual .NET dictionary? Ambiguous title!

Assuming each line is a separate word to populate your 'dictionary':

```
Public Sub PopulateDict()
    For Each word As String In File.ReadAllLines("path")
        AutoComplete.Add(word)
    Next
End Sub
```

Something like this, yes?

Comment: Brother, it has worked! Thank you!. You are a great man, have a nice day!

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark as answer if it helped you.

Comment: @MeanrheiNqiofg Click the checkmark next to the answer

Comment: Ok, I will do it! Can you help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741870/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-a-richtextbox-that-are-pasted-from-a-listbox-vb-ne?noredirect=1#comment55252486_33741870

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you just need to read in the dictionary text file, parse the words from it, and then add them to your ArrayList.

Here's an example:

```
Private AutoComplete As New ArrayList

Private Sub AddDictionary()
    Try
        ' Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("dictionary.txt")

        Dim line As String
        Dim pieces As String()

        ' Read every line in the file
        ' Split the line by the delimiter
        ' Add the individual pieces to the AutoComplete ArrayList
        Do
            line = sr.ReadLine()
            pieces = line.Split(" ")

            For Each piece In pieces
                AutoComplete.Add(piece)
            Next
        Loop Until line Is Nothing

        ' Close the dictionary file StreamReader
        sr.Close()
    End Using
        Catch E As Exception
        ' Let the user know what went wrong.
        MsgBox("The dictionary file could not be read:\n" & E.message, _
                                             MsgBoxStyle.Critical, _
                                             "Error loading file!")
    End Try
End Sub
```

**Note**: I don't know how your dictionary file is formatted, so in my example code I'm just splitting the lines into individual words using spaces.

You could call the `AddDictionary()` sub from your `Form1_Load()` method to add the words to the `AutoComplete` dictionary at startup.

Comment: I see this one can work on the terminal but can it work on a RichTextBox surely? I have tried to edit this code here:     line = sr.ReadLine()

Comment: @MeanrheiNqiofg, `line = sr.ReadLine()` and `pieces = line.Split(" ")` are related to reading in the dictionary file. However, you are right, I forgot to remove the `Console.WriteLine(...)` stuff. I've been working in Java lately where you can write to the console even if you're in a GUI application. I'll edit that in a second.

Comment: I am getting this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. When I paste it on form load. Here is the code that is bringing the problem:                 pieces = line.Split(" ")

Comment: Spencer Doak. Don't work on it, I have found a solution down below.